# Node Postgres Connect query not called

Tags: node.js, node-postgres

I'm using a node-postgres. I wanted to insert the table if not exists before running a select query. But it seems like the table is not created and I'm getting an error when selecting data. This is my node.js file. I want to know what is the fault in this code?

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

const pgClient = new Pool({
  user: keys.pgUser,
  host: keys.pgHost,
  database: keys.pgDatabase,
  password: keys.pgPassword,
  port: keys.pgPort
});

pgClient.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connect called');
  pgClient
    .query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS values (number INT)')
    .catch((err) => console.log("create table error", err));
});

app.get('/values/all', async (req, res) => {
  const values = await pgClient.query('SELECT * from values');

  res.send(values.rows);
});
```

This is the error log

```
connect called
postgres_1  | [61] ERROR:  relation "values" does not exist at character 15
postgres_1  | [61] STATEMENT:  SELECT * from values
api_1       | /app/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:581
api_1       |   var msg = isNotice ? { message: fields.M } : new Error(fields.M)
api_1       |                                                ^
api_1       |
api_1       | error: relation "values" does not exist
```

Comment: `values` is a reserved keyword, you need to quote it `create table "values" (...)` or `select * from "values"`- but I would strongly recommend to find a different name

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanx for the suggestion. I changed the names. but didn't  fix the error